# Could a quantic computer support the data of human memory and the senses of his original body within the next five decades?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction

Could we digitize the memory of a person, including the feelings, the thoughts and the sensorial memory as well ? It could be then put in a quantic computer and used to help « humanising » a AI or « reconstruct » the person for historical purpose.

Digitized images of short term memory is already [experimented on](https://thenewstack.io/mind-reading-ai-optimizes-images-reconstructed-brain-waves) : The images are blurry but it's a good start.

Digital mind uploading research are being done [source 1](https://www.vitamodularis.org/articles/mind_uploading_will_not_lead_to_immortality.shtml)
:  [source 2](https://humanparagon.com/mind-uploading/) and [skill downloading](https://www.mindblowing-facts.org/2013/08/download-knowledge-directly-to-your-brain-matrix-style/) like in the [matrix](https://www.livescience.com/34020-matrix-learning-kung-fu.html) as well

Quantum computing research is a field gathering great interest because of how much it [would help different field of work](https://research.aimultiple.com/future-of-quantum-computing/), [push the limit of AI learning to a whole new level](https://www.analyticsinsight.net/quantum-computing-entwined-with-ai-is-driving-the-impossible-to-possible/) and [solving nonlinear problems](https://research.aimultiple.com/future-of-quantum-computing/)

So, knowing these technologies are realistic, could be the uploading of a human mind memories and feelings possible within the next five decades ?

Comment: Is there a worldbuilding question here? Since early research is proceeding the answer seems to obviously be "yes," but predicting fiction isn't within the scope of the site. What problem are you solving? Also, do you mean [quantum computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing)? because I can't find a quick example of "quantic computing," and the definition of "quantic" is "a homogeneous function of two or more variables having rational and irrational coefficients," which seems irrelevant to CPU design. Could be wrong, though. Citation?

Comment: I think there are temporary and very long-lived temporary memories, every neuron firing is an event and each memory is just a collection of those events, you can temper with these memories by causing them to fire in a controlled way and record them on a computer. Using machine learning you can not only replay the recording it is possible to also forecast with some accuracy... problems is how to distinguish which of those memories are just noise! ;D

Comment: you really need to clarify the context of the question, with current technology in a thousand years, ect.

Answer (score 3):

**We're too far off to tell**

The articles don't tell we're actively moving a consciousness, including the feelings, the thoughts and the sensorial memory. It tells the idea of transfer isn't how many think it is and that we could *simulate*, not copy, some brains. Mind you, that means they simulate "cat" in general and not mr. Wiskers on the windowsill.

We simply don't know enough about brains to copy/upload all the stuff. This simulation can be still far off the real thing, like a very bright light bulb looking like the sun. We used to think people ran on juices, later we compared them to computers and now there's weighted points in neural networks. Each is a hopeful aproximation, but we simply don't know. A neuron is affected by all neurons connected to it by axon, so a weighted network seems correct. But then theres also many other factors, like hormones, reuptake inhibitors, age of the neuron, type of neuron and much more. That is just for function. Storage is much the same. We suspect neuron rhythmic firing and neural pattern activation makes up storage, but the truth is *we don't know*.

So the best conclusion is that we don't know. Theoretically we can probably simulate a brain with 80's technology if we tried hard enough and knew exactly what's happening in someone's noggin. Quantum computing should be no different. But if you don't know, you can't say you can.